# Arkit iOS ( how to make a button to choose from mutiple models)

Tags: ios, button, arkit, realitykit

I’m just starting in iOS development. I’m currently working on a AR app that allows me to choose from different models/equipment to place. I cannot seem to figure out how to add a button or option for the user to choose from the multiple models and select one.

Answer (score 0):

There's no AR button that is offered natively with RealityKit at the moment, but you can add something to your scene and pick it up with a tap gesture on the ARView.

Self promotion warning, but as it's exactly relevant to what you're looking for, I tried to solve this issue recently. Here's a GitHub repo and swift package you can use in your app to add a button in AR pretty easily, handling the gestures for you:

https://github.com/maxxfrazer/RealityUI